# Microsoft VB Compilation Error

Tags: vbscript

I am learner to vbscripting and as a beginner trying to execute the below code. But I keep getting the compilation error [Please see error message below]. I am not sure as I do not see any error in the code. Also, I made sure that I type in all the text instead of copy-paste from web. Please do suggest.

Below is the code

```
<html>
<body>
<script language = "vbscript" type = "text/vbscript">
<document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error Message:**

```
Script: C:\VB Script- Learning\Programmes\1.vbs
Line: 1
Char: 1
Error: Expected Statement
Code: 800A0400
Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error
```

Thanks!

Comment: VBScript is not VB.NET

Comment: try `document.write("Hello World!")` instead of `<document.write("Hello World!")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of your file is HTML with a VBScript script block, but you're apparently trying to run it as a standalone VBScript (`.vbs`). That won't work. Either save the file as `.htm` and open it with Internet Explorer (make sure to add a header `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">` if you have Internet Explorer 11):

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
</head>

<body>
<script language="VBScript" type="text/vbscript">
document.write "Hello World!"
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

or remove all HTML and replace `document.write` with `WScript.Echo` if you want to run it as a `.vbs` file with `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe`:

```vb
WScript.Echo "Hello World!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "<" ([and the ()](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx)) from

```
<document.write("Hello World!")
```

to get

```
document.write "Hello World!"
```